# How to run gRPC client on one machine and gRPC server on another machine?

Tags: python, grpc, communication

I have implemented a simple function which calculates square root of a given number.
I ran server.py on Mac machine and client.py on windows machine. Both the machines are connected to same network.
When I run both client and Server on same machine it works. But when I run Client on another machine it fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 17, in <module>
    response = stub.SquareRoot(number)
  File "/Users/username/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 946, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/Users/username/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 849, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
        details = "failed to connect to all addresses"
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1620574982.491455000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":5420,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1620574982.491453000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":398,"grpc_status":14}]}"
```

clinet.py

```
channel = grpc.insecure_channel('192.168.0.54')
stub = calculator_pb2_grpc.CalculatorStub(channel)
number = calculator_pb2.Number(value=25)
```

server.py

```
server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))

calculator_pb2_grpc.add_CalculatorServicer_to_server(
        CalculatorServicer(), server)

print('Starting server. Listening on port 50051.')
server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50051')
server.start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(86400)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server.stop(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The client need add port at same time, like `channel = grpc.insecure_channel('192.168.0.54:50051')`, then have a try.

If it still not work, try to close the firewall, and check if the network is work correct by telnet, like `telnet 192.168.0.54 50051`